AxiosError: Network Error on iOS (GET request ) with Expo, working fine on Android
it's first time i am asking question in stack overflow . I hope you this will help me to solve the issue.
About project

I am using expo and axios for api request
use hooks for handling the request
using Django as backend
Backend already hosted in pythonanywhere.com . So the protocol is secure with https. When testing my expo using this pythonanywhere not localhost

Problem Overview

Api request (all type of request) working properly in Android and Web
In IOS the POST request working properly But Get request not working
Getting this error when request get request from IOS "AxiosError: Network Error"
I tested the Get request in IOS with other API tester app in IOS then it worked fine

Expo App some codes
app.json

{
  "expo": {
    "name": "MyWard",
    "platforms": [
      "ios",
      "android"
    ],
    "scheme": "com.myward",
    "slug": "myward",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "orientation": "portrait",
    "icon": "./assets/images/logo/thumbnail.png",
    "userInterfaceStyle": "automatic",
    "ios": {
      "bundleIdentifier": "com.myward",
      "supportsTablet": false,
      "jsEngine": "jsc",
      "infoPlist": {
        "LSApplicationQueriesSchemes": ["whatsapp"]
      },
      "runtimeVersion": {
        "policy": "appVersion"
      }
    },
    "splash": {
      "image": "./assets/images/logo/thumbnail.png",
      "backgroundColor": "#ffffff"
    },
    "jsEngine": "hermes",
    "android": {
      "package": "com.myward",
      "googleServicesFile": "./android/app/google-services.json",
      "runtimeVersion": "1.0.0"
    },
    "web": {
      "bundler": "metro",
      "output": "static",
      "favicon": "./assets/images/logo/thumbnail.png"
    },
    "plugins": [
      "expo-router",
      "expo-localization",
      [
        "expo-build-properties",
        {
          "android": {
            "usesCleartextTraffic": true
          }
        }
      ]
    ],
    "experiments": {
      "typedRoutes": true
    },
    "extra": {
      "router": {
        "origin": false
      },
      "eas": {
        "projectId": "48729d2e-6a7b-4b70-811c-c0b03ad2fd89"
      }
    },
    "owner": "myward",
    "updates": {
      "url": "https://u.expo.dev/48729d2e-6a7b-4b70-811c-c0b03ad2fd89"
    }
  }
}


useApiHook


import { useState, useCallback } from "react";
import axios, { AxiosRequestConfig, Method } from "axios";
import { useGlobalContext } from "@/context/GlobalProvider";

interface UseAxiosFetchProps<T> {
  isFetching: boolean;
  fetch: (
    method: Method,
    endpoint: string,
    data?: any,
    token?: string,
    contentType?: ContentType, // Add this parameter
    reloadEffect?: boolean
  ) => Promise<ApiRespond>; // Return Promise
  isFetchedData: boolean;
}

interface ApiRespond {
  ok: boolean;
  data?: any;
  error?: any;
  status: number;
}
type ContentType = "application/json" | "multipart/form-data";
function useApi<T = any>(): UseAxiosFetchProps<T> {
  const [isFetching, setIsFetching] = useState<boolean>(false);
  const [isFetchedData, setIsFetchedData] = useState<boolean>(false);
  const { setIsLoadingOverlay } = useGlobalContext();
  // Fetch function
  const fetch = useCallback(
    async (
      method: Method,
      endpoint: string,
      data?: any,
      token?: string,
      contentType?: ContentType,
      reloadEffect = true
    ): Promise<ApiRespond> => {
      reloadEffect && setIsLoadingOverlay(true);
      setIsFetching(true);

      const config: AxiosRequestConfig = {
        method,
        url: endpoint,
        headers: {
          ...(token ? { Authorization: Bearer ${token} } : {}),
          ...(contentType ? { "Content-Type": contentType } : {}),
        },
        data
      };
      console.log(config);
      let responseData;
      try {
        const response = await axios.request<T>(config);
        responseData = {
          ok: true,
          data: response.data,
          status: response.status,
        };
      } catch (error: any) {
        console.log(error);
        responseData = {
          ok: false,
          status: error.response ? error.response.status : 408,
          error: error.response?.data,
        };
      } finally {
        reloadEffect && setIsLoadingOverlay(false);
        setIsFetching(false);

        if (!isFetchedData) setIsFetchedData(true);
      }
      return responseData;
    },
    []
  );

  return { isFetching, fetch, isFetchedData };
}

export default useApi;



The first GET request i making here

 const verifyUser = useCallback(async () => {
    const token = await _retrieveData("authToken");
    if (token) {
      const response = await fetch(
        "GET",
        API_ENDPOINTS.VERIFY_USER,
        {},
        token,
        "application/json",
        false
      );

      if (response.ok) {
        const data: userDataType = response.data;
        login(
          data.auth_token,
          data.user_preference.language,
          data.user_preference.theme,
          data.profile!,
          data.phone_number
        );
      } else {
        openWelcomeText();
      }
    } else {
      openWelcomeText();
    }
  }, [fetch, login]); // Dependencies: fetch and login

  useEffect(() => {
    verifyUser();
  }, []);




Django backend
settings.py

Django settings for backend project.

Generated by 'django-admin startproject' using Django 5.0.7.

For more information on this file, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/5.0/topics/settings/

For the full list of settings and their values, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/5.0/ref/settings/
"""
import cloudinary
import os
from pathlib import Path
from decouple import config, Csv

BASE_DIR = Path(__file__).resolve().parent.parent



SECRET_KEY = config('SECRET_KEY')

DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['*']


INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'users',
    'profiles',
    'posts',
    'dashboard',
    'subscriptions',
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'django.contrib.postgres',
    'corsheaders',
    'rest_framework',
    'cloudinary_storage',
    'cloudinary',
]


MIDDLEWARE = [
    'corsheaders.middleware.CorsMiddleware',  # This should be first
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': ['backend.authentication_classes.JWTAuthentication'],
    'DEFAULT_PAGINATION_CLASS': 'rest_framework.pagination.PageNumberPagination',
    'PAGE_SIZE': 5  # Number of posts per page
}
AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'users.User'

CORS_ALLOW_ALL_ORIGINS = True

ROOT_URLCONF = 'backend.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')], 
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'backend.wsgi.application'



DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': BASE_DIR / 'db.sqlite3',
    }
}


AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]



LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_TZ = True



MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
MEDIA_ROOT = BASE_DIR / 'mediafiles'
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'staticfiles')

DEFAULT_AUTO_FIELD = 'django.db.models.BigAutoField'



cloudinary.config( 
    cloud_name = config('CLOUDINARY_CLOUD_NAME'),
    api_key = config('CLOUDINARY_API_KEY'),
    api_secret = config('CLOUDINARY_API_SECRET'),
)


EMAIL_BACKEND = 'email_backends.mailjet_backend.MailjetBackend'
MAILJET_API_KEY = config('MAILJET_API_KEY')
MAILJET_API_SECRET = config('MAILJET_API_SECRET')
DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL = 'irshadirshuu1213@gmail.com'

OTP_EXPIRE_TIME = 5


AUTH_TOKEN_EXPIRES_DAY = 30



DEFUALT_PROFILE_IMAGE ="https://static-00.iconduck.com/assets.00/profile-default-icon-2048x2045-u3j7s5nj.png"


AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'users.User'



SITE_URL = 'http://127.0.0.1:8000'


NO_MEDIA_IMAGE = "https://res.cloudinary.com/di4y3lhkc/image/upload/v1728059016/baa0b6kderm7ypuphiyt.avif"
NO_MEDIA_IMAGE = "https://img.freepik.com/premium-vector/no-photo-available-vector-icon-default-image-symbol-picture-coming-soon-web-site-mobile-app_87543-18055.jpg"

Please help me for solving this issue . i have been searching for this solution in internet for 5hrs

Were do you run your backend? And do you run your app on an emulator?
The backend might not be reachable from your app if you are connecting to it using localhost or 127.0.0.1 URLs.

i forgot mention that .  my backend is running in pythonanywhere . So it's a secured protocol with https

Problem Solved. The issue was with the request method of the Axios. In IOS we should pass "GET" for get request, not lowercase "get".
